# Function returning rowset with dynamic column name

Tags: postgresql

I have a generic key/value table that I would like to preprocess in a function to filter by the key, and then name the value according to the key.

The table is like this where `id` points into another table (but really is *don't care* for the purposes of this question):

```
CREATE TABLE keyed_values (id INTEGER, key TEXT, value TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id, key));

INSERT INTO keyed_values(id, key, value) VALUES 
    (1, 'x', 'Value for x for 1'),
    (1, 'y', 'Value for y for 1'),
    (2, 'x', 'Value for x for 2'),
    (2, 'z', 'Value for z for 2');
```

and so forth. The key values can vary and not all IDs will use the same keys.

Specifically, what I'd like to do is to create a function that would produce rows matching a given key. Then it would return a row for each matching `key` with the `value` *named* with the key.

So the output of the function given the key name argument `'x'` would be the same as if I executed this:

```
SELECT id, value x FROM keyed_values WHERE key = 'x';
 id |         x
----+-------------------
  1 | Value for x for 1
  2 | Value for x for 2
(2 rows)
```

Here's my stab, put together from looking at some other SO answers:

```
CREATE FUNCTION value_for(key TEXT) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT id, value %I FROM keyed_values WHERE key = %I', key, key);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The function is accepted. But when I execute it, I get this error:

```
SELECT * FROM value_for('x');
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM value_for('x');
```

I get what it's telling me, but not how to fix that. How can I dynamically define the output column name?

Comment: you can't. Either the column name comes from the function definition or you must name the columns when you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` used in the `WHERE` clause is not an identifier but a literal, so the function should looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION value_for(key TEXT) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT id, value %I FROM keyed_values WHERE key = %L', key, key);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

> If the function has been defined as returning the record data type, then an alias or the key word AS must be present, followed by a column definition list in the form ( column_name data_type [, ... ]). The column definition list must match the actual number and types of columns returned by the function.

Use a column definition list:

```
SELECT * FROM value_for('x') AS (id int, x text);
```

Note that you do not need dynamic SQL nor plpgsql, as the column name is defined in the above list. The simple SQL function should be a bit faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION value_for(_key text)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
    SELECT id, value
    FROM keyed_values
    WHERE key = _key
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

If you do not like being forced to append a column definition list to every function call, you can return a table from the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION value_for_2(_key text)
RETURNS TABLE(id int, x text) AS $$
    SELECT id, value
    FROM keyed_values
    WHERE key = _key
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM value_for_2('x');

 id |         x         
----+-------------------
  1 | Value for x for 1
  2 | Value for x for 2
(2 rows)
```

However this does not solve the issue. There is no way to dynamically define a column name returned from a function. The names and types of returned columns must be specified before the query is executed.